# Redirect to separate succes page after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using bootstrap and have a form I've been using for a while now. It shows the message "Verzonden!" on the same page if the form has been submitted succesfully. now this has to be altered to redirect to a new succes page after the form is submitted.

this is the html I am using

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam & Voornaam" required data-error="Gelieve uw naam in te vullen.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="email" class="email form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-error="Gelieve uw email adres in te vullen.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required data-error="Gelieve uw telefoonnummer in te vullen.">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Onderwerp" required data-error="Gelieve een onderwerp in te vullen.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <textarea id="message" rows="7" placeholder="Bericht" class="form-control" required data-error="Gelieve uw bericht in te vullen."></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>  
              </div>

              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"></i>Verzend!</button>
              <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
              <div class="clearfix"></div>   

            </form>
```

This is the php I am using:

```
 <?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Gelieve uw naam in te vullen.";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Gelieve uw email adres in te vullen.";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// PHONE
if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Gelieve uw telefoonnummer in te vullen.";
} else {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Gelieve een onderwerp in te vullen.";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Gelieve een bericht in te vullen";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}

//Add your email here
$EmailTo = "e-mail address";
$Subject = "Nieuw bericht van website";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Naam: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Telefoonnummer: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Onderwerp: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Bericht: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "Verzonden!";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Er is een fout opgetreden, probeert u aub opnieuw.";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to redirect the user to a new page using the php header function:

```
// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/success-page.php');
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Er is een fout opgetreden, probeert u aub opnieuw.";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Never print or echo anything before the header() redirect call or else it will not redirect the user.

Read the reference here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**UPDATE**

```
// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/success-page.php');
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/success-page.php');
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
```

also added condition for `if($errorMSG == "")`

**Also**

It is a good practice to add the **action** attribute in your form like so:

```
<form action="path-to-your-processing-script.php">
```

If you don't provide that it will submit the form on the same page but still you should give it anyway.

Comment: I have tried the header function before but when I do that it won't submit the form and shows the error message

Comment: Hope you did not echo anything before the header call

Comment: I changed the code like you posted but it shows the "Er is een fout opgetreden, probeert u aub opnieuw." error message it's supposed to do when something goes wrong.

Comment: check the update it will work.
It means that you will be redirected to the new page but your mail has not been sent. try it

Comment: It still won't redirect it.

Comment: There are no error messages or logs, it simply won't do anything when I hit the submit button.